# InfoPath, Rest Service and https

Tags: infopath, forms-services, listdata.svc, https

I am having trouble adding a InfoPath data connection to the SharePoint web services in an extranet environment.  It worked fine in the internal (non-https) test environment.

"InfoPath could not open the XML document:  Not enough storage is available to process this command."

Trying to add a data connection in InfoPath Designer, when I give a valid url (this same url works in the browser)
[image]

Once I click the Next button I get 2 popups.
[image]
[image]

I opened up Fiddler, and when I click the next button I see the request for the XML, and the proper XML response coming back on the third try after two 401 Unauthorized's.

Comment: I could use help with this one too.

Comment: What version of IE are you using? I've seen this with IE 8 & https.